# Custom Gmail color theme

Tags: firefox, script, browser-addons, gmail

I hate Gmail's new color themes. I am looking for a way to change it back to the older color theme. Does anyone know any GreaseMonkey script or Firefox addon to do this?

Comment: How is your CSS? You could make your own using the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) add-on.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the answer now is "just wait".  The [Gmail Themes](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=112508) help page says:

> **What happened to custom themes?**
>
> We're working on a way to bring back the ability to choose your own
>   background.

Answer (score 0):

Use Stylish with [The Return of Old Gmail](http://userstyles.org/styles/57755/the-return-of-old-gmail)  userstyle to get back old Gmail interface in Firefox/Chrome. It is quite easy, just follow the instructions.